# Where do we put the input value in a register on a x64 assembly

Tags: assembly, architecture, 64-bit, x86-64

```
sample:
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp

movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
movl    $1, -16(%rbp)
movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
cmpl    $2, -20(%rbp)
```

Lets says input value is 1 what to set 1 as %rbp or %rsp

than what would be the value of %edi though

Comment: This isn't even 8086 assembly code. This is x64 :-/

Comment: oh  my teacher gave me this and we were learning 8086 so i assumed it was that but what would be the input value of 1 %edi right?

Comment: alright but what would the input value go %edi right?

Comment: what do you mean the input value? the input(or parametric value) to the function sample?

Comment: depending on the type of the parameter value, it could be %rsp or %rbp. The input to the function(the first parameter) is in -16(%rbp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this step by step:

- The function `sample` first sets up a stack frame: `pushq   %rbp; movq    %rsp, %rbp`
- It saves `edi` on the stack: `movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)`. This is OK without explicitly decrementing `rsp` if it's a leaf function.
- It puts some more immediates on the stack: `movl    $1, -16(%rbp); movl    $0, -12(%rbp); movl    $0, -8(%rbp)`.
- It compares the saved value of `edi` on the stack at `-20(%rbp)` with 2. Assuming it does something based on that comparison (maybe the rest of the code is relevant), the input to the function must be the value in `edi`.

Another way to figure this out is the [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), which specifies that `rdi` is used to pass the first argument to functions. You can then further deduce that the first argument to `sample` is a 32-bit wide integer.